# Flutter InAppwebview: This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness warning on ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I am using InAppwebview in flutter app.
When running app from xcode I get security warning: `This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.`
This leads app freeze and crash.
Is it possible to solve this?

WebView Widget:

```
class WebViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  WebViewWidget({
  }) : super(key: Key(url));

  late final InAppWebViewController inAppWebViewController;
  final InAppWebViewGroupOptions webViewOptions = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true,
    ),
    ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    ),
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      transparentBackground: true,
      verticalScrollBarEnabled: false,
      horizontalScrollBarEnabled: false,
      cacheEnabled: true,
      clearCache: false,
      supportZoom: false,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InAppWebView(
      key: Key(url),
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
        url: Uri.tryParse("https://flutter.dev/"),
      ),
      initialOptions: webViewOptions,
      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) async {
        inAppWebViewController = controller;
      },
      onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
        debugPrint("$consoleMessage");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And I am just using webview widget in Material app

```
class GetApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final RemoteMessage? message;
  const GetApp({super.key, this.message});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WebViewWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what url for your webview are you using if posible to know ? it would be useful to know how are you calling this inAppWebview code

Comment: Any solution? @OtabekOchilov